# asp.net mvc difference between OnAuthorization and OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

could someone help to explain the difference between OnAuthorization and OnActionExecuting in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OnAuthorization` gets called when authorization occurs and `OnActionExecuting` gets called before the action method is invoked. Authorization will occure before action execution. This gives you chance to check if user is authorized to execute that action.